# Scroll View does not display components

Tags: swift, swift3

I've started to creating UI programmatically and I'm stuck. I've added blur effect to the view and then to the blur scroll which have just one button but it does not display it. From debuging i can see that there is a button inside. What might be wrong ?

```
(lldb) po blurEffectViewFilters.contentView.subviews
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <UIScrollView: 0x7fd5958a5e00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000253020>; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000002369c0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 568}>


(lldb) po blurEffectViewFilters.contentView.subviews[0].subviews
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <UIButton: 0x7fd593f3bde0; frame = (0 0; 100 50); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000236a40>>


   func initFiltersView() {
        blurEffectFilters = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
        blurEffectViewFilters = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffectFilters)
        blurEffectViewFilters.frame = view.bounds
        blurEffectViewFilters.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        blurEffectViewFilters.isHidden = true

        scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.contentSize = blurEffectViewFilters.bounds.size

        doneButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        doneButton.backgroundColor = .white
        doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)

        scrollView.addSubview(doneButton)

        blurEffectViewFilters.contentView.addSubview(scrollView)

        view.addSubview(blurEffectViewFilters)
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never set the frame of your scroll view:

```
- 0 : <UIScrollView: 0x7fd5958a5e00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds ...
```

In the `initFiltersView()` code, you're setting the contentSize, but not the frame.

Comment: Thank you! I've forgot about that and was not able to see this without "fresh eye"